If more collisions happen with more resistance, why less heat is generated?
I was told the following. Given a wire with a battery connected to a resistor, the current is limited because of the resistance. This resistance is caused by subatomic interactions of the electrons which dissipate heat, losing energy, decreasing the average velocity of the electrons, and so decreasing current, by definition. The higher the resistance, more of these subatomic interactions happen, and so the current is weaker.
This makes me conclude the following. Given a fixed voltage between a resistor, then we have a current. Now, if we substitute the resistor for another with more resistance, more subatomic interactions should happen, lowering the current. And since more subatomic interactions are happening, more energy should be lost in the form of heat, and so more heat should be generated.
In real life, this is not the case. If I increase the resistance, less heat is generated. If more of the interactions are happening, and so more energy is being lost, which is the thing making the current weaker, then shouldn't more heat be generated?
Also, I do know the equation \$P = \frac{U^2}{R}\$. I know that less heat is generated given more resistance. I am trying to understand what is happening in the atom level, if possible.

An incomplete but extremely intuitive explanation is that higher resistance means less current and thus less electrons able to collide.  The reduced number of electrons colliding then reduces the heat deposited.

@user1850479, thank you! I (kinda) guess that explanation even works with the water analogy. When there is dirt clogging the water, initially the water hits the dirt, generating some friction. Afterwards, because it is slowed down after that shock, there is less water to generate friction with the sides of the pipe. So with the dirt, less friction is generated in total. Just a guess of an analogy, really.

why are you trying to understand at atomic level?

@jsotola, to feel like I understand what is happening. Personally, I usually only feel comfortable with something after I feel like I have a deeper understanding. And also: it is fun!

@Schilive Study the Drude model. It's fairly intuitive, I think. (It had to be given it was introduced in 1900, which was four years before Thompson's "plum pudding" atomic model!)

@periblepsis, thank you. I will take a look. It is interesting that so many fields have different models yet how people talk is as if only one model existed, even uni lectures. Physics seems to have a bunch, my chemistry teacher said there were multiple definitions of acidity, and maths is a candyland of different models. I guess knowing this, makes physics feel more human.

@Schilive Models start out as simple as possible, but no simpler. They are modified as new influences are recognized. This happens because simpler models explain observation within measurement error for a time. As higher precision measurements are made, this uncovers unexplainable residual errors in earlier models and requires investigation of the mechanism for the residuals. That's one point. Another is that there are good models to acquire and bad ones. Both may be equal. The solar Ptolemaic model was an equal explanatory model to Copernicus's model. But Copernicus's is far more powerful.

@Schilive So you need to also learn which models have broad application to a wide variety of fields and keep those. Get rid of the models that are narrowly applied. They are not worth their weight to keep. This is an important sifting process. Eventually, you will find that just a few models can be applied to very widely separate fields of application -- showing that only a few ideas are needed to understand most everything you encounter. Those are the ones you want to find and retain. Not the rest, which may be useful for a time and place but are otherwise junk.

@periblepsis, that makes sense. I see electric engineers doing quite well with models that do not explain more unusual things. I guess it is kind of like geometry, which is very useful until you need to calculate the area under x^2 graph.

@Schilive That's a bad example to make your point. ;) Geometry can be easily used to explain the area underneath the x^2 curve. You use little cuboids. You may be able to see by visiting this site. It shows the geometric shape that evolves and solves out at 1/3rd x^3 as the integral. You set up 3 axes. Move incrementally by dx along the x-axis. The first cuboid is 0,0,dx, at x=0. The 2nd is dx,dx,dx at x=dx. The 3rd is `2dx,2dx,dx' at x=2dx. Etc. The 3D shape traced out is then shown in that video.

@Schilive One of the most powerful ideas to keep in mind that there is an exact 1:1 relationship between all of algebra/calculus and all of geometry. Anything you can conceive of in algebra can be described using geometry. And visa versa. Also, take careful note here: the only difference between algebra taught in high school and calculus is that algebra uses variables that may only hold finite values while calculus adds another kind of variable that can only hold infinitesimal values. That's the only addition calculus makes to algebra. Everything else falls out from there.

@Schilive If you need a reference here regarding calculus, once that avoids entirely the Dedekind-Weierstrass limit definition (which I consider to be Rube-Goldberg and annoying), would be to read Abraham Robinson's "Non-Standard Analysis" from the early 1960's. It's excellent and formally introduces infinitesimal variables into mathematics. This makes my earlier point. Abraham Robinson's work is a powerful idea while Dedekind-Weierstrass's limit theorem is more like the Ptolemaic model of epicycles within epicycles, by comparison. Better off learning more powerful ideas, dumping bad ones.

@Schilive Clifford(pure)/geometric(applied) algebra is another super-powerful idea that should replace what's currently taught for vectors and spaces. But that's a whole other kettle of fish for another time. But if interested then start here and then go here. That should get your heart racing!!

@periblepsis, I am not quite that advanced into maths, though I did read a book on set theory from the axioms, and I am starting to read Tao's book on calculus. When I learnt calculus with popular books, including some from my country, they mostly spilt stuff without explaining why. Specially vectors. They looked so simple and innocent at first, then became the reason I dropped my calculus book. What is a dot product, an inverted triangle, why are those "d" things from the integral now a thing of their own?! I did not know Dedekind had something to do with calculus. I only knew Dedekind cuts.

@Schilive The d should be seen as nothing more than a prefix to a variable, so that you know it only holds infinitely small values. So when you see $\int x,\text{d}x$ you should think that this is a product of $x$ and $\text{d}x$ and that this is an area, obviously. If you see $\int x^2,\text{d}x$, you should see $x\cdot x\cdot \text{d}x$ and know that this forms a volume. Of course the area and the volume are infinitesimal. But non-zero. And you can paste these together to make shapes. Unfortunately, most calc books teach the limit method. Luckily Newton wasn't hampered by that.

@periblepsis, the book used just started to use them without explaining or noting, so I got confused, specially when differential equations started... Thinking now, I think I got why $\int_$ is also called a sum symbol! It is like it is summing the product of $x$ and $dx$ "infinitely"! Thank you a lot. Now, the notation makes a lot more sense!

@Schilive In the case of $\int x,\text{d}x$, for example, imagine starting at x=0 and advancing along the x-axis one step at a time, by dx per step, until you reach $x_0$. Each adjacent area is x*dx in area. The 1st tiny area is 0*dx. The next tiny area at x=dx is dx*dx. The next at x=2*dx is 2*dx*dx, and so on. Stacked side by side, you should see a triangle forming that, at the end, is x0 high and x0 wide. The area must be $\frac12x_0^2$. The right calc answer, too!

It is useful to draw an analogy between electric current and wind. At standard temperature and pressure, molecules in the air are traveling in random directions at very high velocities (in the range of 1000 km/hr. Yet a light breeze may travel at only a few km/hr. The breeze velocity is the average algebraic drift velocity. If half the air molecules were traveling at 1005 km/hr toward the east, and half were traveling at 995 km/hr toward the west, the wind velocity would be 5 km/hr.
Similarly, the electrons in say a copper wire might be traveling at 115 km/s in random directions, while the drift velocity of the a current in that wire may be only a few mm/s. Big difference. As a result, the mean time that an electron travels "freely" between collisions is essentially independent of the current's drift velocity, but depends heavily on the material through which the current is passing through. For a given material, the greater the electric field, the greater the (average) drift velocity of the electrons.
In between collisions, electrons accelerate in the direction of the electron current. For a given electric field, the longer they accelerate, the higher their average velocity in that direction. So, materials that allow a long mean free time permit electrons to have a higher drift velocity for the same electric, and thus have a lower resistivity. Materials that have a more restricted mean free time have a higher resistivity.
The resistance of a resistor depends not only on the resistivity of the material, but is also proportional to the length of the resistor, and is inversely proportional to the cross sectional area. Thus, a resistor could be made from silver (which is a better conductor than copper) if it had the right dimensions.
Current is proportional to the drift velocity times the cross sectional area of a conductor (or resistor), and also depends upon a constant related to the material (essentially the density of mobile electrons within the material).
So now lets put these facts together.
If we have 10 V applied to a long copper wire, with a resistance of say 10 \$\Omega\$, there will be a certain number of electron collisions in a given length of time, and electrons will drifting (like the wind) at a certain velocity, and a certain amount of power will be dissipated (we know from \$P=V^2/R\$ that it will be 10 watts.
Now suppose we double the length of the wire. The number electron collisions per unit volume will stay the same. But the number of electron collisions per unit time over the whole volume will double, because there is twice as much wire.
The potential difference between the ends of the wire will stay the same, but because that difference is spread out over twice the length, the electric field will be half as intense. Thus, the electrons will only accelerate half as much between collisions, and the drift velocity will thus be cut in half.
Since kinetic energy is proportional to velocity squared, the energy converted to heat with each collision will be cut to one fourth. However, the power dissipated is proportional to the energy randomized per collision times the number of collisions per unit time, and since the latter factor doubled, the power dissipated will be cut in half.
And that is an illustration of the number of collisions doubling, but the power dissipation being cut in half. However, we could have doubled the resistance in a different way. Instead of doubling the length of the wire, we could have used a wire with half the cross sectional area.
In this case, the number of collisions per unit time will be cut in half, because there is half the volume. Because the length of the wire and voltage remain the same, the intensity of the electric field (\$\vec{E}\$) will remain the same, so the drift velocity of the electrons will remain the same. Since the drift velocity remains the same, but the number of collisions is halved, the power dissipated will be halved. What about the resistance. Well, resistance is the voltage divided by the current. If the drift velocity stays the same, but the cross sectional area of the conductor/resistor is halved, then the current is halved. So the resistance in this case is doubled, even though the number of collisions per unit time is halved.
In general, it is not always true that more collisions per unit time means more resistance. In fact, if we consider the extreme case where there is no wire at all but only empty space, there are no collisions, but infinite resistance. Whether or not more collisions is associated with more resistance depends on how that "more resistance" is created. Increasing the length of a conductor/resistor will increase both resistance and collisions. Decreasing cross-sectional area of a conductor/resistor will increase resistance, but decrease total electron collisions per unit time.

That is very interesting. Thank you for saying it so simply. Now I wanna learn electromagnetism even more...

Nice qualitative explanation. The ideas of mean free path and mean free time could have been added, I suppose. For air, the key ideas of viscosity, density, and pressure determine much of the mean free path length: $\text{length} \propto \frac{\text{viscosity}}{\sqrt{\text{density}\cdot \text{pressure}}}$. May be cute to provide the analog relationship of these, but for conduction band electrons. +1

"If more collisions happen with more resistance, why less heat is generated?" You neglected the title question.  Also if the resistance drops to less than that of the current source then heat will drop.  But nice analogy.

@D.A.S. Ah, no. I explained why with more collisions and more resistance there is less heat generated. But thanks for the downvote.

@MathKeepsMeBusy  That is not true with current sources or voltage sources with load R < source R while increasing load R. Your welcome for the constructive criticism

@D.A.S., I think they answered my question. They gave an example of doubling the length of a wire, affirmed the number of collision increase, and then explained why, even though more collisions happen, half the power is dissipated, which he said is because the particles are at half velocity. So, I feel like it answered my question. They could have added more maths, but I was looking for a more conceptual answer, so I think it is great.

@D.A.S. source impedance and load matching have nothing to do with the question. "Given a fixed voltage between a resistor, then we have a current. Now, if we substitute the resistor for another with more resistance, more subatomic interactions should happen, lowering the current." Since the voltage across the resistor is fixed, source impedance is not relevant.

I have one question, which is more mathematical, I guess if it is ok. When you said the velocity of the electrons will be half as intense, did you mean the average? Because doesn't the magnitude of the electric field decrease by the inverse square law?

Doubling the length of the wire while keeping the voltage across it the same will halve the intensity of the electric field, whose symbol is $E$ or $\vec{E}$. The value of $\vec{E}$ determines the acceleration of electrons. If you know about line integrals, a line integral of $\vec{E}$ gives a voltage. In space $\vec{E}$ does fall off according to an inverse square law. But in a straight uniform conductor (or resistor) of uniform cross section, $\vec{E}$ is constant from one end to the other. Its magnitude is the voltage from one end to the other divided by the length.

@MathKeepsMeBusy, that is really cool. Thank you.

@Schilive I had a realization about the relationship between resistance and number of collisions and incorporated it in my answer. You should re-read the last 3 paragraphs.

@MathKeepsMeBusy, that is an awesome addition, and I think it makes the whole point make more sense. Thank you for taking the time.

Your assumptions are wrong.  The charge migration speed increases with the current. But the current will not always increase with conductance, Y or the inverse, R.
Power will always start to increase until the load resistance matches the source resistance. We call a matched impedance and maximal power transfer theorem.. This might be an overload point but in theory, it will be an MPT point.
Power can dissipate from voltage source \$P_d=\frac{V^2}{R}\$  or a current source \$P_d=I^2R\$.
Atomic motion
When free electrons collide between conductor atoms, they lose some kinetic energy. The atoms, now vibrating more due to the energy imparted by the electrons, increase in temperature. This energy loss by the electrons is what we observe as resistance, and the corresponding increase in atomic vibrations is what we perceive as heat.
In summary, increasing current creates heat by causing electrons moving through a material to collide with more atoms. This transfers kinetic energy to these atoms. This energy loss by the electrons is what we observe as resistance, and the corresponding increase in atomic vibrations is what we perceive as heat.
In most conductors as the temperature increases, the resistance slowly increases. This positive temperature coefficient or PTC is a known quantity for each metal.  Metal Oxides have the same effect while semiconductors such as Silicon PN junctions have the opposite or NTC effect in both forward voltage drop and slightly in incremental resistance, which makes diodes good thermometers but poor for parallel device thermal runaway effects.

This doesn't really answer the question, as it doesn't even mention the number of collisions.

Wrong, The Op assumed that was defined somehow, the question was about a contradiction in his understanding.

" I am trying to understand what is happening in the atom level, if possible."  1st understand the macro level.

read the title of the question for the contradiction.
